# Why Custom Resource failed to stabilize in expected time in AWS Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm want a create a new Custom Resource with CloudFormation to obtain the result of the current date minus X days and when I create the lambda function, I obtain the error:

> Resource failed to stabilize in expected time.

My code is:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - test
      - prod
      - sbx
  DaysToSubstract:
    Description: Days To Substract to calculate dates to ingest with RedshiftLoader
    Type: Number
    Default: 1
Resources:
  lambdaDateRedshiftLoader:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    DependsOn:
      - lambdaDateRedshiftLoaderRole
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          from datetime import date, timedelta
          import cfnresponse
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              current_delta = date.today() - timedelta(days=event['DaysToSubstract'])
              current_delta_str = current_delta.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
              responseData['Dates'] = current_delta_str
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DaysToSubstract: !Sub '${DaysToSubstract}'
      Description: >-
        Calculate yesterday date to obtain start and end date to load the data
        with RedshiftLoader
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !GetAtt lambdaDateRedshiftLoaderRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 30
  lambdaDateRedshiftLoaderRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'a3m${Environment}-datesRL-lambda-role'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
      Path: /service-role/
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub 'a3m${Environment}-lambda-datesRL-lambda-logs-policy'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - !Sub >-
                    arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/lambda-datesRL-uyc:*
  lambdaRL:
    Type: 'Custom::Value'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt lambdaDateRedshiftLoader.Arn
Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionOutput:
    Value: !GetAtt lambdaRL.Dates
    Description: Return Value of Lambda Function (Date minus x days)
```

I'm using `cfnresponse` with `SUCCESS` and using `!GetAtt lambdaRL.Dates` in the output.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are they any CloudWatch Logs errors for the lambda which fails?

Answer (score 2):

Your Lambda function was **giving errors**, therefore it never had a chance to call `cfnresponse.send()`. This meant that CloudFormation kept waiting for a response.

Here's an updated version of the Lambda function:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
import cfnresponse, os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    current_delta = date.today() - timedelta(days=int(os.environ['DaysToSubtract']))
    current_delta_str = current_delta.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    responseData = {}
    responseData['Dates'] = current_delta_str
    cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
```

The problems were:

- The environment variables are passed through `os.environ()`, not `event()`
- The `DaysToSubtract` value was coming through as a `string`, not an `int`, so the `timedelta()` function was failing (Careful... spelling of `Substract` vs `Subtract`)
- The `responseData` dictionary was not initialized, so it was giving a `NameError: name 'responseData' is not defined` error

I highly recommend that you **develop the Lambda functions in the console first**. Then, once they are working, move them into the CloudFormation template. That makes debugging a lot easier.

Oh, also please note that **Custom Resources are called when the stack is Created, Updated and Deleted**. This can lead to some unexpected behaviour, especially during the `Delete` operation. It's normally a good idea to insert an `if` statement to only run the code during the `Create` phase by using:

```py
if event['RequestType'] == 'Create':
```